# AVAudioPlayer Object Sound Not Playing - Swift

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, nsobject

I have created an object class of AVAudioPlayer below in order to play a noise:

```
class MusicAudio: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    var bassAudio   : AVAudioPlayer! = AVAudioPlayer()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        let bassAudioPath       = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Raw", ofType:"mp3")

        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bassAudioPath!)
        bassAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)
        bassAudio.currentTime = 0
        bassAudio.volume = 1.0
        bassAudio.delegate = self
    }

    func adjustAudioLayerState(volumeOn:Bool, layer:AudioLayerState) {

        if layer == AudioLayerState.Bass {
            self.bassAudio.prepareToPlay()
            self.bassAudio.play()
        }
    }
}
```

To play the noise, I call the class via:

```
@IBAction func testSound() {
    var sound:MusicAudio = MusicAudio()
    sound.adjustAudioLayerState(true, layer: AudioLayerState.Bass)

}
```

However I am not getting any audio played back, can anyone spot a problem with my implementation?

**Edit: After rdelmar answer**

```
var bassAudio   : AVAudioPlayer! = AVAudioPlayer()

class MusicAudio: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        let bassAudioPath       = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Raw", ofType:"mp3")

        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bassAudioPath!)
        bassAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)
        bassAudio.currentTime = 0
        bassAudio.volume = 1.0
        bassAudio.delegate = self
    }

    func adjustAudioLayerState(volumeOn:Bool, layer:AudioLayerState) {

        if layer == AudioLayerState.Bass {
            self.bassAudio.prepareToPlay()
            self.bassAudio.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get any sound because your MusicAudio class is being deallocated. You need to make the var, sound, a property, not a local variable.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var sound = MusicAudio()

    @IBAction func testSound() {
        self.sound.adjustAudioLayerState(true, layer: AudioLayerState.Bass)
    }

}
```

Comment: This has fixed the problem, however the fix (see edit in question) in my head seems messy - is there a more suitable way i should be doing this in Swift or am I being paranoid?

Comment: @Ryan, I don't see anything in your edit that's different from what you originally posted. The change needs to be in the view controller class where you have the IBAction.

Comment: Oh I see!, in my edit i moved "var bassAudio:AVAudioPlayer! = AVAudioPlayer()" outside the class itself at the top (which did fix the problem too). I've implemented what you meant and it works though now :)