# Swift - AVAudioPlayer not playing sound

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have a sound called `speeding.mp3` and I am trying to make a AVAudioPayer instance with it by doing this in the root of the class:

```
let speedingAudioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("speeding", withExtension: "mp3")!)
```

Then when I run the app it throws an error but I don't know why this is happening. The `speeding.mp3` file is in the Bundle Resources drop down in Build Phases so it should find it fine. If I try to print out the URL in the simulator and paste it into Safari it loads and plays the file like normal. I am importing AVFoundation into the class and the framework into the project.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code snippet to debug your error,

```
if let URL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("speeding", withExtension: "mp3") {
    do {
        let speedingAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: URL)
    } catch  let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
} else {
    print("No such file exist")
}
```

Comment: It just stops on the third line and comes up with an error saying `Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2`

Comment: Could you list the exception, what exactly does it say ?

Comment: It doesn't say anything else and it only happens at runtime.

Comment: Ok, put exception break point and use debugger to see what actually happens there

Comment: Well there is now no other way than looking at your code. Could you somehow put it in dropbox or github such that I can take a look at it.

Comment: I would if I could but the project is currently classified, I can send you screenshots of anything you like.

Comment: Is there another way to play a short sound? If I try to build the project in my simulator after I upgraded Xcode it comes up with 4 errors. http://pastebin.com/TTZfgpLy

Answer (score 1):

I found another question where the var is placed outside the class because otherwise it would be deallocated by the phone.

[AVAudioPlayer Object Sound Not Playing - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302996/avaudioplayer-object-sound-not-playing-swift?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CustomAudioPlayer {
  var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playSound("sound_file_name")
  }

  func playSound(soundName: String)
  {
    let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(soundName, ofType: "mp3")!)
    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:alertSound)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }catch {
        print("Error getting the audio file")
    }
  }
}
```

Try this code for playing the sound.